# Google Apps Script - get URL of File in Drive with File Name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am attempting to create a form in Google Spreadsheets which will pull an image file from my Drive based on the name of the file and insert it into a cell.  I've read that you can't currently do this directly through Google Scripts, so I'm using setFormula() adn the =IMAGE() function in the target cell to insert the image.  However, I need the URL of the image in order to do this.  I need to use the name of the file to get the URL, since the form concatenates a unique numerical ID into a string to use the standardized naming convention for these files.  My issue is that, when I use getFilesByName, it returns a File Iteration, and I need a File in order to use getUrl().  Below is an snippet of my code which currently returns the error "Cannot find function getUrl in object FileIterator."

```
  var poNumber = entryFormSheet.getRange(2, 2);
  var proofHorizontal = drive.getFilesByName('PO ' + poNumber + ' Proof Horizontal.png').getUrl();

  packingInstructionsSheet.getRange(7, 1).setFormula('IMAGE(' + proofHorizontal + ')');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the file name exactly, You can use `DriveApp` to search the file and getUrl()

```
function getFile(name) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
  while (files.hasNext()) { 
    var file = files.next();
    //Logs all the files with the given name
    Logger.log('Name:'+file.getName()+'\nUrl'+ file.getUrl());
  }
}
```

If you don't know the name exactly, You can use [`DriveApp.searchFiles()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)) method.

Comment: I'm trying this out, but I'm not getting anything returned as the file URL.  Here is a snippet of the code that I'm running to test this; the variable "poNumber" is declared above:

  var drive = DriveApp;
  var proofHorizontal = drive.getFilesByName('PO ' + poNumber + ' Proof Horizontal.png');
  Logger.log(proofHorizontal);
  
  //Gets image file URL
  while (proofHorizontal.hasNext()) {
    var proofHorizontalUrl = proofHorizontal.next().getUrl();
    Logger.log(proofHorizontalUrl);
  }

Could the issue be that there is only one file being found, so ".hasNext" would be false?

Comment: You're correct.  The issue was an error with a variable that I was concatenating in my getFilesByName string.  This should work, now that I've caught that error.

Answer (score 1):

You're close - once you have the [`FileIterator`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator), you need to advance it to obtain a File, i.e. call `FileIterator.next()`.

If multiple files can have the same name, the file you want may not be the first one. I recommend checking this in your script, just in case:

```
var searchName = "PO + .....";
var results = DriveApp.getFilesByName(searchName);
var result = "No matching files";
while (results.hasNext()) {
  var file = results.next();
  if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType. /* pick your image type here */ ) {
    result = "=IMAGE( .... " + file.getUrl() + ")");
    if (results.hasNext()) console.warn("Multiple files found for search '%s'", searchName);
    break;
  }
}
sheet.getRange( ... ).setFormula(result);
```

You can view the available MimeTypes in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)